# How to create one store per instance in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Sometimes it would be useful to create one store per instance in Redux applications. The creator of Redux itself created a Gist which describes how to achieve this: https://gist.github.com/gaearon/eeee2f619620ab7b55673a4ee2bf8400

I asked this question already in the Gist but I think StackOverflow would be a better place for this question:

I wonder how to `dispatch` actions to the component's own special store? Is there a way to access the `store`-prop of the `<Provider />` for each `<SubApp />` (and their child-components)?

For example: I have some API classes that call `dispatch` after fetching data from a remote server. But since I can't import the "normal" store, what would be the best way to deal with custom stores to make them available for other classes/files/services?

## Update 1

So I got it working, but I think it's a really dirty way (mind the `UGLY?` comments inside the code):

**Provider:**

Create a store per instance by creating the store inside the constructor:

```
export default class OffersGridProvider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.store = createStore(reducers);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.store}>
        <OffersGridContainer offers={this.props.offers} />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**Container:**

The Provider injects a `dispatch` method for **this** store to my `OffersGridContainer` which I can use to dispatch actions just to the store of this instance:

```
class OffersGridContainer extends React.Component {    
  componentDidMount() {

    // UGLY???
    const { dispatch } = this.props;

    let destinationIds = [];
    this.props.offers.forEach((offer) => {
      offer.to.forEach((destination) => {
        destinationIds.push(destination.destination);
      });
    });

    // MORE UGLY???
    destinationsApi.getDestinations(dispatch, destinationIds);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <OffersGridLayout destinations={this.props.destinations} />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = function(store) {
  return {
    destinations: store.offersGridState.destinations
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(OffersGridContainer);
```

**API method:**

Just use the `dispatch`-method that I've passed as argument to my API method:

```
export function getDestinations(dispatch, ids) {
  const url = $('meta[name="site-url"]').attr('content');

  const filter = ids.map((id) => {
    return `filter[post__in][]=${id}`;
  }).join('&');

  return axios.get(`${url}/wp-json/wp/v2/destinations?filter[posts_per_page]=-1&${filter}`)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch(getOffersGridSuccess(response.data));
      return response;
    });
}
```

## Update 2

Just received a hint about `mapDispatchToProps` in the comments, so my `Container` now looks like this:

```
class OffersGridContainer extends React.Component {    
  componentDidMount() {
    let destinationIds = [];

    this.props.offers.forEach((offer) => {
      offer.to.forEach((destination) => {
        destinationIds.push(destination.destination);
      });
    });

    this.props.getDestinations(destinationIds);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <OffersGridLayout destinations={this.props.destinations} />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = function(store) {
  return {
    destinations: store.offersGridState.destinations
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
  return {
    getDestinations: function(ids) {
      return destinationsApi.getDestinations(dispatch, ids);
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OffersGridContainer);
```

## Update 3 (the final answer)

Now everything works! Here's to code:

**Provider:**

```
export default class OffersGridProvider extends React.Component {    
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.store}>
        <OffersGridContainer offers={this.props.offers} />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**Container:**

```
class OffersGridContainer extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const destinationIds = this.props.offers.reduce((acc, offer) => {
      return [...acc, ...offer.to.map(d => d.destination)];
    }, []);

    this.props.getDestinations(destinationIds);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <OffersGridLayout destinations={this.props.destinations} />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = function(store) {
  return {
    destinations: store.offersGridState.destinations
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
  return {
    getDestinations: function(ids) {
      return dispatch(destinationsApi.getDestinations(ids));
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OffersGridContainer);
```

**API method:**

```
export function getDestinations(ids) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    const url = $('meta[name="site-url"]').attr('content');

    const filter = ids.map((id) => {
      return `filter[post__in][]=${id}`;
    }).join('&');

    return axios.get(`${url}/wp-json/wp/v2/destinations?filter[posts_per_page]=-1&${filter}`)
      .then(response => {
        return dispatch(getOffersGridSuccess(response.data));
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a second parameter to `connect`: `mapDispatchToProps` which allows you to keep the component unaware of the dispatch.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please review my update?

Comment: Next update: I should use `thunk` as middleware so that I don't have to pass `dispatch` as argument and return a function inside my `getDestinations` method.

Comment: Yes, this looks about how I set things up.  You can probably make things a bit more terse around the edges, but it looks like you are on solid ground now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making api calls in components directly, I suggest you to use `redux-thunk` package.

Next, you should pass `mapDispatchToProps` function as second argument to `connect` function, to inject action creator functions to component:

```js
import { getDestinations } from '../actions';

class OffersGridContainer extends React.Component {    
  componentDidMount() {
    // Tip.
    const destinationIds = this.props.offers.reduce((acc, offer) => {
      return [...acc, ...offer.to.map(d => d.destination)];
    }, []);

    // instead `destinationsApi.getDestinations(dispatch, destinationIds)`
    // call action creator function
    this.props.getDestinations(destinationIds);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <OffersGridLayout destinations={this.props.destinations} />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = function(store) {
  return {
    destinations: store.offersGridState.destinations
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
  return {
    // this function will be available in component as   
    // `this.props.getDestinations`.
    getDestinations: function(destinationIds) {
      dispatch(getDestinations(destinationIds));
    }
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OffersGridContainer);
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried the first approach, but the store remains the same. I want to render my `SubApp` a few times, but if the data changes in one `SubApp`, all other instances of `SubApp` gets updated too. I think the `customStore` must be created inside the `constructor`, but than I loose the possibility to export it. I'm going to create a little Fiddle and add the link in a new comment.

Comment: @Slevin, ok, it would be more easier to understand with fiddle.

Comment: Oh, I figured it out (but I don't think that this is "best practice"...). Going to update my question.

Comment: @Slevin, I completely rewrited my answer, pls take a look :)

Comment: Thanks, I just got the same idea :D (look at the comment in the original question). This is how it works now. Great!

Comment: Oh, one more question left :) I rewrote my API method like this: `return axios.get(url).then(response => { return getOffersGridSuccess(response.data); });` but now I get the warning, that Actions have to be plain object, but `thunk` is included as middleware: `const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));`

Comment: I think you async action is not returning a function. It should be like: `const asyncAction = function() { return function(dispatch) { // ... making api calls and calling `dispatch` } };

Comment: @Slevin, Little tip: To avoid variables, as it is not functional approach, instead using `forEach` I suggest you to use `reduce` function, take a look at updated answer.