# Redux One store per instance communicating with each other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have multiple audio player component instances. I use one store per instance like in the following links: https://gist.github.com/gaearon/eeee2f619620ab7b55673a4ee2bf8400 and [How to create one store per instance in Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821882/how-to-create-one-store-per-instance-in-redux).

This works great for updating single audio players at a time.
The problem is that each audio player needs to be able to communicate with each other somehow on certain actions, (i.e when one audio player starts playing the others need to pause). How can I do this with a single store per instance? At the moment I don't see how I can communicate to the other store instances.

I tried to just have one store and multiple instances within it but then the state is shared between all audio players which isn't what I want for some properties (i.e when one audio player starts playing they all start playing).

Is their any way to have some state properties like this?

Unique state properties per instance audio player:

```
{
    paused: false,
    mp3: ""
}
```

Shared state properties between all audio players:

```
{
    globalPause: true, //Pause all other audio player instances that have this set to true
    globalVolume: true  //Modify volume of all other audio player instances that have this set to true
}
```

AudioPlayer:

```
class AudioPlayer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Player className="default">
                <Gui>
                {//Other Components here}
                </Gui>             
                <BrowserUnsupported /> 
            </Player>
        );
    }
}

AudioPlayer.options = {
    selector: "audio-player",
    muted: true,
    autoplay: false,
    mp3: //Mp3 url,
};

export default AudioPlayer;
```

AudioPlayerTwo:

```
class AudioPlayerTwo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Player className="default">
                <Gui>
                {//Other Components here}
                </Gui>             
                <BrowserUnsupported /> 
            </Player>
        );
    }
}

AudioPlayerTwo.options = {
    selector: "audio-player-two",
    muted: true,
    autoplay: false,
    mp3: //Mp3 url,
};

export default AudioPlayer;
```

Index:

```
createPlayer(AudioPlayer);
createPlayer(AudioPlayerTwo);
```

createPlayer:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    ...state.Player, 
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({Player: bindActionCreators(PlayerActions, dispatch)});

export default createPlayer = (WrappedComponent) => {
    WrappedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WrappedComponent);

    const store = createStore(reducer, {
        Player: defaultValues
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <WrappedComponent />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById(WrappedComponent.options.selector));
}
```

Actions (A couple of them with the same format like this):

```
export const play = (time) ({
    type: "PLAY",
    time
});

export const volume = (volume) ({
    type: "VOLUME",
    volume
});
```

Reducer:

```
const play = (state, action) => {
    if(state.srcSet) {
        return updateOption(state, {
            paused: false,
            newTime: !isNaN(action.time) ? action.time : state.currentTime 
        });
    }
}

const volume = (state, action) => updateOption(state, {
    volume: limitValue(action.volume, 0, 1)
});

const updateOption = (existingObject, newValues) => ({
    ...existingObject, 
    ...newValues
});

export default (state={}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {        
        case "PLAY": 
            return play(state, action);
        case "VOLUME":
            return volume(state, action);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `actions` ?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja edited post.

Comment: Why are you trying to create 2 stores? Instead have one store and two reducers for each player. then you can access state of other players. If you have different stores, It's may not be a `redux` thing.

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja But then they share the same state between all properties. If I dispatched `play()` with just one store it would play both audio players.

Comment: Then have two action types say `PLAY_PLAYER_ONE`, `PLAY_PLAYER_TWO` like this

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja Ah okay. But Each player can be dynamically created by the developer, (i.e there could be 1 player or 100). How would I do it without hardcoding?

Comment: In that case, figure out some elegant way to do this. As of now give some id to each Player and `actionTypes` will be concated with that id to match that particular player reducer.

Comment: Your AudioPlayer component should include a playerId prop to identify which bit of state to take props from (e.g. `state.players[props.playerId]`) and that you include in action payloads to tell the reducer which player the action came from. You'll also want a CREATE_PLAYER action if you need to dynamically add them. Also, avoid having multiple React roots unless you really need it (very few even very complex apps do) - just render the list of players in your store.

Comment: @TomW That's what I have ended up doing with only one store now. Each player has an Id now. I also have a state which has an object list of players in it where the name matches the id of the player. I then pass the ID to each action and in the reducer I update the player who's name matches the passed in ID. In mapStateToProps I then select only the player which just got updated by using ownProps ID. This sound good to you? It just sucks that I have to pass ID to every single action.

Answer (score -1):

Your going to need to use a redux middleware, my suggestion would be redux-saga and a pub/sub library such as postal.js.

Basically what you want is a middleware the publishes actions, that the other middlewares are listening (subscribed) to. So for example if you hit play on one player the middleware publishes this event and all the other players are listening via the pub/sub library and when they see this message they can pass a 'stop' action to their local redux stores.

Comment: I think I can do it without using extra middle-ware which just looks complicated.